# Em R, contar palavras e introduzir um quebra de linha

Tags: r

Caros, boa tarde

Suponha que eu tenho um vector da seguinte maneira

> legenda<- c("Gostei muito da atuação" , "Gostei pouco da atuação", "Nem gostei e nem desgostei")

Eu desejo criar uma função que introduza de maneira automática o separador \n a cada dois palavras

Por exemplo

> funcao(legenda, 2)
>
> "Gostei muito\n da atuação" , "Gostei pouco \n da atuação", "Nem gostei \n nem desgostei"

Seria interessante generalizar e determinar os intervalos de introdução do quebra linha

por exemplo, uma função desta maneira

> funcao(vector, c(2,3,5))

onde c(2,4,5) significa que a cada elemento de vector será introduzido um primeiro \n depois de dois palavras, um segundo \n depois de 3 palvras e um terciero \n depois de 5 palavras.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Você pode fazer isso usando [regular expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression):

```
library(stringr)

legenda   <- c("Gostei muito da atuação" , "Gostei pouco da atuação", "Nem gostei e nem desgostei")

legenda2  <- str_replace_all(string      = legenda,
                             pattern     = "(\\w+\\s\\w+)",
                             replacement ="\\1 \n")
legenda2
[1] "Gostei muito \n da atuação \n"    "Gostei pouco \n da atuação \n"   
[3] "Nem gostei \n e nem \n desgostei"
```

Para alterar a quantidade de palavras é só colocar mais `\\w+\\s`

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer isso usando a função `nbreak()` que eu criei:

```
devtools::install_github("igorkf/breaker")
library(breaker)

legenda <- c("Gostei muito da atuação" , "Gostei pouco da atuação", "Nem gostei e nem desgostei")

purrr::map_chr(legenda, ~nbreak(.x, n = 2))
# [1] "Gostei muito\nda atuação"     "Gostei pouco\nda atuação"     "Nem gostei\ne nem\ndesgostei"
```

Eu ainda não a implementei para diferentes vetores, como você mencionou (é uma boa ideia)!